# How do we deal with atheists with angry views on islam and religion?

Tags: other-religions

Asalamualykum

I believe everyone is entitled to believe in what they chose in peace. However I am noticing a growing amount of atheists are constantly writing anti Islam content that is pretty upsetting and offensive.
 How do we deal with these types of people?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the Islam.StackExchange policy should be? Because in that case, you should [ask on meta](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Or do you mean to ask what to in general about people who write things against Islam?

Comment: Are you sure its anti-islam (or anti-religion)? It could be that they are speaking logically and rationally for which the implications may make your uncomfortable?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17995/what-qualities-the-suras-have-that-humans-are-not-able-to-duplicate/23055?s=1|0.0585#23055) could help.... the rest, patient is the key. Leave them until they meet the day when they cannot [regret](http://quran.com/89/15-26).

Comment: You say `I believe everyone is entitled to believe in what they chose in peace` yet you are upset because you don't like what they believe in? You can't both keep the cake and eat it. Choose one.

Comment: Allah (swt) tells you how to reply to Atheists (disbelievers in general), so please refer to Quran, if you don't want to read the whole Quran, someone could point you to specific verses.

Answer (score 1):

No matter where you are, here (SOF), in a chatroom, out in the world, remember one thing: If you have knowledge (i.e. you're a scholar) and you can reply then do it, but if you are not then learn and read first.

Also in Islamic Science there are priorities, for example you should learn how to pray and live like a Muslim first, then you learn in depth of other divisions like (how to argue with non-believers).

So in brief, learn and read first, cause if you don't know what you're talking about you'll do more harm.

Please note, I'm not a scholar, this is not a fatwa rather a simple answer to a known issue.