# Why is Quran a miracle?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

Is it true that the Quran is a miracle of eternity?

What are the signs of miraculousness of the Qur'an now?

What is extraordinary in this book that I can now understand and wonder now?

If this is true, how can I today understand this miracle and believe in the religion of Islam by the Qur'an?

Answer (score 2):

OK I will answer all your Question in Three Phases
The first Question was

`Is it true that the Quran is a miracle of eternity?`

Yes it is a **continues miracle** for all century.

That it is because from Allah meaning and word with Arabic language and challenge Humans to make one  like it:

> Allah said  قُلْ فَأْتُوا بِكِتَابٍ مِّنْ عِندِ اللَّهِ هُوَ أَهْدَى مِنْهُمَا
>   أَتَّبِعْهُ إِن كُنتُمْ صَادِقِينَ (سورة القصص، 49)

said bring to me any book from Allah better than it if you say the truth

> and make it simple "قُلْ فَأْتُواْ بِعَشْرِ سُوَرٍ مِّثْلِهِ مُفْتَرَيَاتٍ "
>   (سورة هود، 13)

said bring to me only 10 chapters like this Quran
 and lastly make it most simple just one in the same quality as Quran Ayah

> فَأْتُواْ بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِ "
>   (سورة البقرة، 23)

and this challenge for all creatures Humans and Devils

> "قُل لَّئِنِ اجْتَمَعَتِ الإِنسُ وَالْجِنُّ عَلَى أَن يَأْتُواْ بِمِثْلِ هَـذَا الْقُرْآنِ لاَ يَأْتُونَ بِمِثْلِهِ وَلَوْ كَانَ بَعْضُهُمْ لِبَعْضٍ ظَهِيراً "
>   (سورة الإسراء، 88)

**no one and no one will ** win this challenge for that it is miracle

Then you asked `What are the signs of miraculousness of the Qur'an now?`

for now the challenge also their for Arabic and non Arabic to made book like Quran .

and asked `What is extraordinary in this book that I can now understand and wonder now?`
 For those century their more challenges for them in their Sciences because many Quran Talk about Theories science before it been made 
example for that Allah said

> Allah said : ( أولم ير الذين كفروا أن السماوات والأرض ``كانتا رتقا ففتقناهما وجعلنا من الماء كل شيء حي أفلا يؤمنون ( 30 ) )

means that the earth and sky was one thing and Allah separate the which this theory is the big explosion was in the Quran before those modern century.

Lastly you ask `If this is true, how can I today understand this miracle and believe in the religion of Islam by the Qur'an?`

This answer for this question be simple when you see to Quran as miracle book from Allah and truth that if it from him it say and order me what I can do and what it possible.

Comment: What if I make a surah? As above challenge, If I sing a surah in Persian language and in size of (for example) Kothar, I will victory the challenge? And can I clam that the Quran may not a `miracle of eternity`?

Comment: @MGae2M I think the answer of servant-of-wiser on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17995/what-qualities-do-the-surahs-have-that-humans-are-not-able-to-duplicate is addressing the necessary conditions however I'm not sure what the basis of that is!

Comment: if you made single ayah as Allah Quran you get the challenge but same but the best Arabic talker in the `ancient Saudi Arabia` couldn't made how could you ?

Comment: The challenge of ten chapters was reduced to one chapter

Answer (score 0):

Ten surah reduced to one surah , then the one surah was reduced to ONE AYAT!!!!!!!    The language was so beautiful and eloquent that even the best poets of the region could not.come close to the flow or the meter of the Arabic. Thus, it was concluded that it had to come from Allah.

Comment: I don't see how does this even try to answer the question?